# WP 5.1 Edit/New post/page shows blank white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating to WordPress 5.1, when I Add/Edit a page/post, the screen is white (blank).
I had tried without success:

1. Disabling other plugins and themes
2. Clearing the Browser cache
3. Trying a different Browsers and Computers (including mobile)
4. All plugins and themes are up to date
5. Reinstalled 5.1
6. I’ve also installed Health Check Troubleshooting.

Any help resolving the issue would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should activate debug logging by setting

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

in `wp-config.php`

After doing this, re-try your attempt of adding/editing a post and then visit the debug.log in `/wp-content` folder. Post the entries here that match the point in time and one can narrow the issue further down.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I **updated my chrome browser and problem resolved**.
Now I can edit and create new posts and pages.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked:

**Plugins > Add New > Search: [Disable Gutenberg](https://refrefdergisi.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=plugin-information&plugin=disable-gutenberg&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550)**

install it. That's it.

src: https://tasvirwebsolutions.com/solved-creating-a-new-wordpress-post-gives-blank-white-page/